# Any Open Source Threat Modeling Tools?

Tags: open-source

Is there any open-source threat modeling tool - sort of like SDL Threat Modeling from Microsoft?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [The Open Web Application Security
>   Project](https://www.owasp.org/) (OWASP) is a 501c3
>   not-for-profit worldwide charitable
>   organization focused on improving the
>   security of application software. Our
>   mission is to make application
>   security visible, so that people and
>   organizations can make informed
>   decisions about true application
>   security risks. Everyone is free to
>   participate in OWASP and all of our
>   materials are available under a free
>   and open software license.

---

[**Threat modeling area**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Threat_Risk_Modeling), towards the bottom of the page;

### Appendix: Alternative open-source Risk Management tools

- [OSMR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osmr/)
- [MARCO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/marco/)
- [CORAS Risk Assessment Platform](http://sourceforge.net/projects/coras/)
- [ISO 17799 Risk Assessment Toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ratiso17799/)
- [Easy Threat Risk Assessment](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easy-tra/)
- [ARMS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arms-17799/)
- [Minaccia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minaccia/)
- [ThreatMind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/threatmind/)
- [Open Source Requirements Management Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osrmt/)

Comment: Most (all?) of these have been dead for a few years now (as of late 2016).

Answer (score 0):

Here's some others

MyAppSecurity (Not open source but free) [ThreatModeler](http://www.myappsecurity.com/threatmodeler/download/)

Trike [Octotrike](http://www.octotrike.org/)

Amenaza Securitree